# Easy way to convert and copy a solution to VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We have a VS2005 solution and I want to convert it to VS2010.  I figured an easy way to keep the old solution around (for other developers) is to create new sln and proj files specific to 2010.  I hoped that the conversion wizard would do this easily but it doesn't seem to.

Anyone know an easy way to copy all .sln and .csproj files, then convert to VS2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go into the file system and copy those files to another location, open solution and allow it to do conversion. Then recopy the originals back using a different filename.

Comment: This will work, but is not easy.  Maybe you could write a script to automate it to keep projects in sync?  It would only be one way though.

In any case, I never found a good alternative.  We ended up making all developers (and build machines) use VS 2010.